# how to accessing next page on this web site?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

There is a website, from which I would like to extract specific link.
I have managed to do it but only for one site. There are 133 sites, from which links I need. Could you please advice me how to do it ?

So far I was able to build this. I understand that it should somehow use array "pages" but I do not know how to tell the script to loop over it and treat it as new site. Thank you in advance.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time
pages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133]
links = []
for page in pages:
    url =  urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.derekprince.org/Media/")
    content = url.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    result = soup.findAll('a', {"class": "media_recording_file_download" })
    links.append(result)
```

Comment: Use ```selenium```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again Selenium become the simplest and lest demanding solution for web **scraping** problem :) In case if someone needs it or would have a similar problem, here is the solution. I have used google chrome to copy xpath and find class names.

```
from selenium import webdriver                                                                            
pages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133]


driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/grzegorz/Documents/chromedriver")                                        
driver.get("https://www.derekprince.org/Media/")                                                          
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("media_recording_file_download")

for i in pages:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='media_pager_top']/a[2]").click()         
    for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("media_recording_file_download"): 
        i.click()
```

Answer (score -1):

*There are multiple issues in one question - So I would recommend you to improve it.*

I am just answering the first one in detail for the second one, ask a new question please.

#### How to deal with iteration?

Instead of your `list` you can go with `range()` - Pass two arguments (start,stop) to `range()` and it will generate integers starting from the start number to stop -1.

```
for i in range(1,6):
    print(f'This is my iteration #{i}')
```

To connect your variable with the `string` you can use pythons f'string.

#### Hint for your next question.

This website deals with a `form` so you have to performe a post request, that contains your `page` variable.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it does not help much to be honest.
list or iteration is rather cosmetic change... Could you please elaborate more about how to accessing next page on this web site ?

Comment: As @HedgeHog mentioned you need to know more about the forms data as .aspx is not some website you can scrap just by getting the page.

Comment: how to accessing next page on this web site ?  This should be the title for your next focused question

Comment: as sugested I have changed title of this question.

Comment: anyone can give a suggestion how to scrap through aspx, please?

Comment: Kindly re-asking for help here :)
All i need is how to gather links from all pages for .aspx, surely someone did something like that before...